# Replacing a duplex switch with a dimmer and the duplex switch has a 3 way and is fed from a different circuit

Tags: wiring

[image][image]This switch is a duplex 3 way switch controlling my dining room fixture (not 3 way) and also my porch light (3 way) each fed from a different circuit.  I would like a dimmer on my dining room light fixture.  I bought a duplex dimmer with 3 way capability on each switch, but it only has one feed.

The question is can I use this and connect both feeds to the one on the duplex dimmer?  Or do I return this and look for a duplex dimmer that accommodates 2 feeds?

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring inside the box in question please? Also, what make/model is your dimmer?

Comment: If on different circuits connecting them together will probably let the magic smoke out. If you turn the breaker off for the 3 way the other one stays on? That would be a separate branch circuit if they both turn off with 2 breaker there might be some possibility’s